# Get attr src from string using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string

```
str = '<iframe width="100%" height="300" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=vi&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Vimcom+91+b%C3%A0+tri%E1%BB%87u&amp;aq=&amp;sll=15.125395,108.795111&amp;sspn=0.034096,0.038581&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=Vimcom+91+b%C3%A0+tri%E1%BB%87u&amp;hnear=&amp;radius=15000&amp;t=m&amp;ll=21.011605,105.849323&amp;spn=0.048074,0.051498&amp;z=13&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=vi&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Vimcom+91+b%C3%A0+tri%E1%BB%87u&amp;aq=&amp;sll=15.125395,108.795111&amp;sspn=0.034096,0.038581&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=Vimcom+91+b%C3%A0+tri%E1%BB%87u&amp;hnear=&amp;radius=15000&amp;t=m&amp;ll=21.011605,105.849323&amp;spn=0.048074,0.051498&amp;z=13" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">Xem Bản đồ cỡ lớn hơn</a></small>'
```

How to get attr src using javascript (no-jquery) from str string?
Thank!

Comment: May I know why do you need to get src from `string` str instead of elementID?

Comment: Hacky, but For this particular string: `str.split('src=')[1].split('>')[0]`

Comment: Parsing with any kind of DOM parser would load the iframe. Would that be acceptable for you?

Comment: @karthikr: Seriously, a regex would be cleaner :-) And you forgot the quotes.

Comment: @user1671639 because str added by user from textbox

Comment: @karthikr You should be posting this as an answer.  Working perfectly, I checked in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/dtgbN/) :)

Comment: its very hacky. @user1671639 It Is not at all useful for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:
`str.match(/.*src="([^"]+).*/)[1]`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var str = '<iframe width="100%" height="300" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=vi&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Vimcom+91+b%C3%A0+tri%E1%BB%87u&amp;aq=&amp;sll=15.125395,108.795111&amp;sspn=0.034096,0.038581&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=Vimcom+91+b%C3%A0+tri%E1%BB%87u&amp;hnear=&amp;radius=15000&amp;t=m&amp;ll=21.011605,105.849323&amp;spn=0.048074,0.051498&amp;z=13&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=vi&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Vimcom+91+b%C3%A0+tri%E1%BB%87u&amp;aq=&amp;sll=15.125395,108.795111&amp;sspn=0.034096,0.038581&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=Vimcom+91+b%C3%A0+tri%E1%BB%87u&amp;hnear=&amp;radius=15000&amp;t=m&amp;ll=21.011605,105.849323&amp;spn=0.048074,0.051498&amp;z=13" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">Xem Bản đồ cỡ lớn hơn</a></small>';

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = str;
alert(div.childNodes[0].getAttribute('src'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Dogbert/hxjpB/

Make sure the string starts with the `<iframe>` or the first childNode would be a textNode, and this wouldn't work. (There are more robust ways to do this which would work in those cases too, if you want.)

Answer (score 0):

You may find interesting using regular expressions on your code: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_regexp.asp

This regex should work:

```
/src="[^\ ]*"/i
```